# How to render different versions of the same file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, controller, partial

For example I have this file:

**_goal.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <%= goal.name %>
    <span class="label label-info"><%= goal.deadline.strftime("%d %b %Y") %></span>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It is being rendered from the **home** page:

```
 <h1><b>Goals</b></h1>
   <%= render @unaccomplished_goals %>
   <%= render @accomplished_goals %>
<% end %>
```

How can we wrap an accomplished goal with `<span class="label label-info-success">` but if it is an unaccomplished goal keep it `<span class="label label-info">`?

In the **controller**:

```
@accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished
@unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
```

Here was my **latest attempt**, which just made them all `-info`:

```
<% if @unaccomplished_goals == true %>
  <span class="label label-info"><%= goal.deadline.strftime("%d %b %Y") %></span>
<% else @accomplished_goals == true %>
  <span class="label label-warning"><%= goal.deadline.strftime("%d %b %Y") %></span>
<% end %>
```

Maybe you'll have more luck :)

Thank you so much.

Comment: How is `accomplished` defined? Is there a flag on your model, like `accomplished?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper method that returns the correct classes for the goal's status. In application_helper.rb:

```
def deadline_label_class(goal)
  if goal.accomplished?
    'label label-info'
  else
    'label label-warning'
  end
end
```

This assumes that `Goal` has an instance method called `accomplished?` which returns true/false. You may have to write that method if it doesn't exist or use some other criteria.

Then use the helper in the **_goal.html.erb** template:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <%= goal.name %>
    <span class="<%= deadline_label_class(goal) %>">
      <%= goal.deadline.strftime("%d %b %Y") %>
    </span>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome Infused! The colors work but for some reason the tag drops to the line below instead of staying inline like before. I don't why this is or how to fix it. I tried overriding it in my css file with `.<%= deadline_label_class(goal) %> { display: block-inline }` but doesn't work or with `.deadline_label_class`. Any ideas?

Comment: Infused if I reposition the span above name in my file it works fine so I can just go with that, but I have a more impressing issue, which is in the code (which I left out in the question) I also have this line:  `<%= raw goal.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t), class: 'label label-info' }.join(' ') %>` if I try to switch in `<%= raw goal.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t), class: "<%= deadline_label_class(goal) %>" }.join(' ') %>` I get an ugly error: `syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')' ..._buffer.safe_append='" }.join(\' \') %> ... ^` etc

Comment: I'll take a look into that infused if I hate the repositioning :)

Comment: Ah, since that is already inside of `<%= %>` use `class: deadline_label_class(goal)` instead.

Comment: Awesome I was putting in the "" Thanks again very helpful :)